# How to Get Date from Row Range to Populate into a Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am looking for some help on a date function. I am trying to have a "dashboard" page if you will for employee training. I have created sign in sheets for each training topic with their name and rows next to their names for the date they completed the course to be entered at the time of sign in/out. I am needing that specific date from that row range of cells to autofill into a cell on the main "dashboard" page once a date gets entered onto that sheet. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### `'Dashboard - Smith, J.'!A1:C3`

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **John Smith** | **FILTER** | **VLOOKUP** |
| **2** | Course 1 | 10/02/2023 | 10/02/2023 |
| **3** | Course 2 | - | - |

| **Cell** | **Formula** |
| --- | --- |
| B2 | `=FILTER('Course 1'!B:B, 'Course 1'!A:A=$A$1, "-")` |
| B3 | `=FILTER('Course 2'!B:B, 'Course 2'!A:A=$A$1, "-")` |
| C2 | `=IFNA(VLOOKUP($A$1, 'Course 1'!A:B, 2, 0), "-")` |
| C3 | `=IFNA(VLOOKUP($A$1, 'Course 2'!A:B, 2, 0), "-")` |

##### FILTER

The [FILTER function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) allows you to filter a range of data based on criteria you define.
**Syntax:**  `=FILTER(array,include,[if_empty])`

##### VLOOKUP

The [VLOOKUP function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) allows you to lookup a value in a table or a range by row.
**Syntax:**  `=VLOOKUP (lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])`

#### `'Course 1'!A1:B3`

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Employee** | **Completed** |
| **2** | John Smith | 10/02/2023 |
| **3** | Bob Jones | 10/23/2023 |

#### `'Course 2'!A1:B3`

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Employee** | **Completed** |
| **2** | John Willis | 10/05/2023 |
| **3** | Bob Jones | 10/18/2023 |